# Area 51 Discussion Zone privileges link is sending to a page that does not exist

Tags: bug, area-51, broken-link

When clicking on the privileges link from within my users tab:

[image: area 51 discussion zone privileges link]

I was taken to http://area51.stackexchange.com/help/privileges:

[image: page note found]

It needs to be updated to take you to 1 of 2 places.

The first candidate would be http://area51.stackexchange.com/privileges, which does exist:

[image: area 51 privileges]

The second candidate, https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges, is more appropriate since we are within the Area 51 **Discussion Zone**, however, this privileges page has virtually nothing on it:

[image: area 51 discussion zone privileges]